# Match specific text which has square bracket before and after (~ start & end of line)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I am looking to match specific parts of text which is surrounded in square brackets. Either the text before a colon up to the word boundary/whitespace before or if no colon exists just the text before the end square bracket. For example

`[Object testThis:anotherObject];` should match `testThis`

`[Object create];` should match `create`

`[Object create:YES andTest:NO];` should match both `create` as well as `andTest`.

I was trying something like the following with a look behind to check for an open square bracket and a look ahead to find the close square bracket but I wasn't able to get it to match anything in between.

```
(?<=\[) .*:(?=\])
```

Comment: In what language are you trying to do this?

Comment: Objective-C, pattern syntax is that specified by [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp).

Comment: Are you talking about a balanced text (brackets) approach (requirement)? Otherwise `(\w+)\s*[:\]]` is a solution. If you are talking about balanced text, the regex engine must be capable of doing recursion. This requires matching the whole bracketed text, then recursing cores of outer brackets until there are no more brackets. Along the way you pick up the desired text.

Comment: @sln It doesn't have to be balanced, that would be pretty good if it was though. Just regex for the basic rules as listed in the question would suffice in the great majority of cases.

Comment: Yeah, in parsing language, you have to have knowledge of what its constructs are. Otherwise, you plow fields while blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, maybe something like this:

```
(?<!:)\b[^: ]+\b(?=:[^\[\]]+\]|\])
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/jE8eU5)

The regex started as:

```
[^: ](?=:[^\[\]]+\])
```

To get `testThis` in 1, `create` and `andTest` in 3. This would get the words before a colon only if they are between square brackets (assuming they are balanced). Then for the second case, I added the negative lookbehind and the or `\]` in the lookahead, plus the word boundaries to the match to prevent partial matches.

EDIT: As per comment:

```
(?<!:)\b[^: ]+\b(?=:[^\]]+\]|\])
```

Should work with `[Object create:YES andTest:[Object anotherTest]]` as well.

EDIT2: Possible alternative:

```
[^\]]+?(\b[^: ]+\b)[:\]]
```

But here, you have to fetch the results from the first capture group.

Comment: That works like a charm thank you! One last question, with regex would it be possible to capture the same things if they were within square brackets within those squared brackets. As in: `[Object create:YES andTest:[Object anotherTest]];` or `[[Object anotherTest] create:YES andTest:andTest]`. The later actually works straight away which is brilliant, the first not so. Thanks again.

Comment: @Joshua I think you can use this one `(?<!:)\b[^: ]+\b(?=:[^\]]+\]|\])` (it doesn't have the `\[` in the negated class). I had put `\[` just in case there might be 'false' captures, but I guess that shouldn't be a problem after all.

Comment: The Edit1 regex matches [[Object `TestONE]create`:[Object `TestTWO`]]. He didn't say that `]` is a boundry, but its a natural part of this type of data construction. Also, I think he said there could be a whitespace before the colon/bracket (after the second `\b`). Eventually, he will find something that breaks it because the rules go deeper than this.

Comment: @sln That's easily fixed by adding a `]` in the negated class to capture `(?<!:)\b[^\]: ]+\b(?=:[^\]]+\]|\])` for edit 1 regex. The second doesn't work through, and I preferred the first one anyway, since it appears to be more robust.

Comment: I havn't got it at hand, but I tested the `EDIT: As per comment:` one with a slight mod `(?<![:\]])\b[^\]: ]+\b\s*(?=:[^\]]+\]|\])` that seems to fix those issues, can't remember. There is something natural in this regex that always blocks `[`. Mine specifically blocks at the end `[^\[\]\s]`

Answer (score 1):

I would go simple. You specify a word boundry or whitespace before `:` or `]`.
Why make it so complex, a simple

Edited:

`(\w+)\s*[:\]]\s*\w*`

should do it.

If you want to expand the definition of the "text", just change the `\w` to  whatever that definition is.

Edit2 - Final answer (until specs change again):

`(\w+)\s*(?::\s*[^\[\]\s]*|\])`

Comment: That doesn't work. It gets `anotherObject` as well as `NO` from OP's original samples.

Comment: @Jerry - Yeah, thats right. I wanted the OP to explain the permutations he needs to design for. There are a hundred possibilites in his examples. Its not that easy. Edited my answer to satisfy OP's examples, in this case, I avoided using a `(?<!:)` before `(\w+)` in favor of adding `\s*\w*\w*`. And didn't add any forward looks, because these are irrelavent. These questions remind me of the ones saying, `"I just want to parse out certain C/C++ comments that are preceded by a variable like this` `dVar = 2.3; // comment`"` It just ain't gonna be like you think.

Comment: That's better. Except it doesn't work with one of the samples OP has but didn't put in the question, being `[[Object anotherTest] create:YES andTest:andTest]`. But yea, I get what you mean, it's just sometimes I like the little challenges ^^

Comment: @Jerry - Well, added change for hidden specs.